SQL query to get hourly data for highest revision number per day
I have two related tables as below.
Master table:



ID
Date
Rev




1
2022-01-01
1


2
2022-01-02
1


3
2022-01-02
2


4
2022-01-03
1



Detail table:



ID
hour
Capacity




1
1
1


1
2
2


1
3
3


1
4
4


2
1
5


2
2
6


2
3
7


2
4
8


3
1
9


3
2
10


3
3
11


3
4
12


4
1
13


4
2
14


4
3
15


4
4
16



The capacity for each day will be saved multiple times as revision. For some day there would be 1 revision, some other day 3 based on number of times data saved.
Now I need to take data from these two table in a single query with largest revision of each day. Expecting 12 rows of data for the 3 existing days in the chosen month.
I wrote the below query
select a1.wdcm_date as wdcm_date, c1.wdcd_block_no as wdcd_block_no, c1.wdcd_capacity as wdcd_capacity, 
      c1.wdcd_approval as wdcd_approval, a1.wdcm_revision_no as wdcm_revision_no
from wb_declared_capacity_master a1, wb_declared_capacity_detail c1
where a1.wdcm_internal_id = c1.wdcd_ref_id  and to_char(a1.wdcm_date,'MM yyyy')='01 2022' 
and wdcm_revision_no = (select max(wdcm_revision_no) from wb_declared_capacity_master where to_char(wdcm_date,'MM yyyy')='01 2022')

This returns only the data with revision number 3 dates.
My expected result should be



Date
hour
Capacity
Rev




2022-01-01
1
1
1


2022-01-01
2
2
1


2022-01-01
3
3
1


2022-01-01
4
4
1


2022-01-02
1
9
2


2022-01-02
2
10
2


2022-01-02
3
11
2


2022-01-02
4
12
2


2022-01-03
1
13
1


2022-01-03
2
14
1


2022-01-03
3
15
1


2022-01-03
4
16
1



How to get all 12 rows (all hours for each qualifying revisions)?

Why don't the column names in your query match the column names in your tables?

Yet another case that's simpler and faster with DISTINCT ON:
SELECT m.date, d.hour, d.capacity, m.rev
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (date)    -- simple & fast
          id, date, rev
   FROM   master
   WHERE  date >= '2022-01-01'  -- ! sargable = faster
   AND    date <  '2022-01-02'  -- !
   ORDER  BY date, rev DESC
   ) m
LEFT   JOIN detail d USING (id)
ORDER  BY date, hour;

See:

Select first row in each GROUP BY group?

And avoid expressions on columns before filtering like the plague.
to_char(date,'MM yyyy') = '01 2022') is hugely expensive. It has to be computed for every row in the table before your filter can be applied. Use a "sargable" filter. Much faster, especially with applicable index, but even without. Related:

Subtract hours from the now() function
Optimize BETWEEN date statement

Subtle detail: I use LEFT JOIN to preserve every qualifying day in the result, even if detail are missing. May or may not be possible with your data model. But won't hurt in any case.

Your sub query only returns one revision number, not a different number for each date.
What you need is a 'correlated' sub query, where the sub query refers to a source value in the outer query...
Also, really do not use , for joins, which has been replace with ANSI syntax since 1992!
Finally, don't use meaningless aliases such as a1, c1, etc. It makes code harder to read, not easier. Aliases should have meaning.
SELECT
   cm.wdcm_date as wdcm_date,
   cd.wdcd_block_no as wdcd_block_no,
   cd.wdcd_capacity as wdcd_capacity, 
   cd.wdcd_approval as wdcd_approval,
   cm.wdcm_revision_no as wdcm_revision_no
FROM
   wb_declared_capacity_master   AS cm
INNER JOIN
   wb_declared_capacity_detail   AS cd
      ON cd.wdcd_ref_id = cm.wdcm_internal_id 
WHERE
   to_char(cm.wdcm_date,'MM yyyy')='01 2022' 
   AND
   cm.wdcm_revision_no = (
      SELECT MAX(wdcm_revision_no)
        FROM wb_declared_capacity_master
       WHERE wdcm_date = cm.wdcm_date
   ) 

